# removing the trailing (space) %20 after images

Tags: codeigniter, space, codeigniter-url, trailing

I have been getting an errors from my error log of missing images. The reason the are appearing missing is because after the image file extension there is a blank space like this

> uploads/images/thumbs/natasha.jpg%20

This 404 error does not occur always, it happens some times.

I have built the project on the Codeigniter php framework.

What should I do to remove the trailing space?

Comment: Which code calls this URL? You generate it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to trim and decode it first

```
$image = trim(urldecode($image));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the trim() function.
(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

e.g.

```
$image = " this/is/the/path/to/myimage.jpg ";
// Note the spaces around the string

$image = trim($image);
// $image now equals "thisis/the/path/to/myimage.jpg"
// Note: no spaces
```